# What could possibly attack the paint like this?

Tags: paint, paint-scratches

All of a sudden, after I took my 2009 VW Golf to a car wash, I noticed some places where the paint started going off... I doubt it is from the washing. I suspect that gum from the apricot tree from above my parking spot might be guilty for this, although I'm not sure. Could it also be from bird poop? Or just the age of the paint + heat/cold?

And is there any way I can extra protect the paint? Other than changing the parking place, perhaps...

See some images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: In the future, it works a lot easier to actually upload the image to Stack Exchange. We can see it without having to go out to other sources and it may help someone else in the future if you ever kill the images from Google or what have you.

Comment: Exactly, I can't see the pictures from where I am. If you use the edit tool, you should be able to include the pictures directly.

Comment: I am aware of that, but the images were larger than 2 MB and I couldn't upload them. I first tried to post them, and when I couldn't, I choose to provide the links to Google Drive.

Comment: @SorinAdrianCarbunaru embedded them for you.

Comment: @SorinAdrianCarbunaru Looks like to me that the clear coat is failing due to age. UV is hell after almost a decade of exposure.

Comment: Eggs will also do that if you don't clean them off of the clear coat.  I had that happen to a car that was left sitting for a year while I was out of the country.  I don't know how long the eggs were on there, well less than a year worth.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it is a not so good repaint of a panel. This would be likely if it is all on a couple body panels. Or if the whole car was repainted.

Comment: I am the second ownet of the car. I personally haven't repainted it. I cannot guarantee that the previous owner didn't do it, but I doubt...

Comment: You could lend a paint thickness checker and check for yourself.